# Suitescript 2.0 - Call customer record to remove sublist lines

Tags: mapreduce, netsuite, suitescript

I am running into an issue with calling the customer record from a passed value on my mapped section of my mapreduce script. It is sending me a debug error of "TypeError: Cannot find function load in object 262059". Where 262059 is the internal ID of the customer passed from the `getInputData` function.

NetSuite debug image...
[image: Netsuite debug image...]

Here is the coding of the function that is throwing this error.

```
function removeLine(r,recordId){
        try{
            log.audit({title:"removeLine"});
            var customerRecord = r.Load({
                "type": r.Type.CUSTOMER,
                "id": recordId,
                "isDynamic": true
            });
            log.debug({details:"recordId = " + recordId});
            var index = rec.getLineCount('item');
            log.debug({detaisl:"index = " + index});

            for (var cnt = 0; cnt < lineCount; cnt++)
                {
                    log.audit({details:"Round " + cnt})
                    rec.selectLine({
                        sublistId: "item",
                        line: cnt
                    });
                    rec.removeLine({
                        sublistId: "item",
                        line: cnt
                    });
                }
            log.debug(recordId + " Item Pricing has been removed.");
            record.save();
        }catch(exception){
            log.debug("removeLine Error Message:",exception);
        }
    }
```

What am I missing or not understanding? I appreciate your guidance.

Brad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem lies where you load the record:

```
var customerRecord = r.Load({
    "type": r.Type.CUSTOMER,
    "id": recordId,
    "isDynamic": true
});
```

It should be `r.load`, not `r.Load` as JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks of the code change recommendation. However, I still received the same error - "TypeError: Cannot find function load in object 262059". Is it because the code is seeing customerId as a text and is looking for a number?

Comment: Please show how you are invoking `removeLine`; my guess is that you are passing in the `recordId` where you should be passing in a reference to the `N/record` module.

Comment: Eric - I do appreciate you taking the time to help with this. Here is the code that invokes remvoeLine.

Comment: `function map(context) {
     try{
      var searchResult = JSON.parse(context.value);
          log.debug("searchResult", searchResult);
         var customerId = searchResult.id;
          log.debug("customerId", customerId);
         //var customerName = searchResult.altname;
          //log.debug("customerName", customerName);
         //var entityId = searchResult.entityid;
          //log.debug("entityId", entityId);
                  
         removeLine(customerId);
         
     }catch(exception){
      log.debug("Map Error Message:",exception);
     }
    }`

Comment: Removing the comment lines for a cleaner look                          
 `function map(context) {
     try{
      var searchResult = JSON.parse(context.value);
          log.debug("searchResult", searchResult);
         var customerId = searchResult.id;
          log.debug("customerId", customerId);removeLine(customerId);
         
     }catch(exception){
      log.debug("Map Error Message:",exception);
     }
    }`

Comment: Ok, I was able to get past this error by changed r.load({ to record.load({. Now onto the next error :-)

Comment: Right so look at your definition of `removeLine` and then your invocation of it. You've defined it as `function removeLine(r, recordId)`, but then you invoke it with `removeLine(customerId)`, so you are passing in the Customer ID where you should be passing in a reference to the Record module. I would just remove the first parameter from your definition of `removeLine` so that it is just `function removeLine(recordid)`.

Comment: Thanks Eric! That worked. I removed the "r" and made it removeLine(recordId). I was able to make it to the 'for" loop and now working on the "SSS_INVALID_SUBLIST_OPERATION","message":"You have attempted an invalid sublist or line item operation. You are either trying to access a field on a non-existent line or you are trying to add or remove lines from a static sublist." error.

Comment: Got it to work! First Suitescript ever produced and I appreciate your assistance!